# Can't run specific test specs based on namespace using sbt at the shell

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest, specs2

I'm trying to run my specs2 tests from the shell as part of my CI build.  When I run the following command on my local windows machine it runs the appropriate specs: specs defined in the Unit namespace.

```
sbt test:compile "test-only Unit.*"
```

However, on my build machine (ubuntu) it appears to ignore the namespace parameter to test-only and as a result runs all the tests.  Single quotes don't seem to make a difference.  When I enter the sbt console and then execute the command (test-only Unit.*) it works as expected.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, I missed that the quotes were right... It works for me, so maybe the particular `sbt` script you are using is evaluating the arguments in a non-argument-preserving manner. Which sbt are you using?

Comment: What if you try `sbt test-only Unit.* directly`? This should recompile the tests if needed anyway.

Comment: @Daniel I'm using sbt 0.12.1 on both my windows and ubuntu build machine.

Comment: @Eric That should do the trick, but I have the same problem.  It runs all tests in my test directory.